# Unable to change the date using Javascript in Selenium WebDriver

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

I am unbale to change the date which is visible in the Web Page using Javascript code as below:

HTML Source Code:

> ```
>  /**
>  * <input id="Datefromdate"
>  * class="ui-input-text ui-body-b ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset" type="text"
>  * placeholder="Click here to select From Date" id="Datefromdate"
>  * name="Datefromdate" required="required"
>  * onchange="setMinEndDate(this.id);" ele_type="start"
>  * class="ui-input-text ui-body-b ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset"
>  * readonly="">
>  */
> ```

Javascript used to change Date:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) getDriverInstanceForThread();
        WebElement element = getDriverInstanceForThread().findElement(By.id("Datefromdate"));
        js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', '10/16/2014')",element);
```

Date field displays current date, if I try to get the value using "value" attribute as shown below, but unable to change its value using "value" attribute using js as shown above.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("Datefromdate")).getAttribute("value");
```

output = 09/16/2014

Please help to find the solution..

Answer (score 0):

In your code `setAttribute()` is not valid Javascript.

You need to change this line:

```
js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', '10/16/2014')",element);
```

to this:

```
js.executeScript("arguments[0].value='10/16/2014'");
```

Comment: Actually, when called on a JS DOM element, setAttribute is an absolutely valid javascript method for most browsers after IE8. [Reading here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_all.asp).

Using `.value` may be a slightly more versatile approach, but this is *not* the answer to the question.